# Rewriting rule for spaced folders and all html files

Tags: regex, rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^(assets|font|fonts|img|images|css|files|js|favicon.ico)(.*)$    webroot/$1$2
```

This rule will apply on the folder starting with above name. now how to add a rule which applies for html files also similer to `|[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+.html|`

Please suggest proper rule as above code notworking

Comment: Provide more information with examples. How should `*.html` files be rewritten?

Comment: Do you mean that? ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(.html)$   webroot/$1$2

Comment: @Braum I do not want result to be $1$2, It should rewrite in single variable, that is $1.Here $2 is for anything come after this .html (Please see rule above)

Comment: @Aunbhava: I am using cakephp 3.x and all html file are putted in webroot folder. default rule transfer all request to index.php file located in this folder except for folder defined above. now i want to include rule for those html files which are physically available there.